# How to assign a two-dimensional Boolean array ( google , or-tools,Scheduling)

Tags: python, scheduling, or-tools, cp-sat

I have three boolean arrays: shift_list, shift_assignment, work。
shift_list：rows represent shift, columns represent time.
shift_assignment：rows represent employee, columns represent shifts
work: rows represent employee, columns represent time.

**I want to change the value in work by changing the value in shift_assignment, for example:**

if I set shift_assignment[0,2]==1 then work's Row e0 should be [0,0,1,1,1,0,0] , the [0,0,1,1,1,0,0] row shoud come from  shift_list's row s2.
my purpose is to control work array through shift_assignment,and the value of work must come from shift_list.

sorry,my english!

[image]

[image]

[image]

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

shift_list=[[1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
            [0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,0],
            [0,0,0,0,1,1,1]]

shift_assignment={}        
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        shift_assignment[i,j] = model.NewBoolVar("shifts(%i,%i)" % (i,j)) 
        
        
work={}
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(7):
        work[i,j] = model.NewBoolVar("work(%i,%i)" % (i,j)) 
        
for i in range(5):
    model.Add(sum(shift_assignment[i,j] for j in range(5))==1)
        
for i in range(5):
    model.Add(how can i do?).OnlyEnforceIf(shift_assignment[i,j])
    

model.Add(shift_assignment[0,2]==1)
model.Add(shift_assignment[1,1]==1)
model.Add(shift_assignment[2,3]==1)
model.Add(shift_assignment[3,4]==1)
model.Add(shift_assignment[4,0]==1)

res=np.zeros([5,7])
status = solver.Solve(model) 
print("status:",status) 

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(7):
        res[i,j]=solver.Value(work[i,j])
print(res)
```

Comment: Please describe you question more precisely. I do not understand 'by the value in'.

Answer (score 1):

thank to @Laurent Perron!

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

shift_list=[[1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
            [0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,0],
            [0,0,0,0,1,1,1]]

num_emp = 5
num_shift=5
num_time = 7

work={}
shift_assignment={}  


for e in range(num_emp):
    for s in range(num_shift):
        shift_assignment[e,s] = model.NewBoolVar("shifts(%i,%i)" % (e,s)) 
        

for e in range(num_emp):
    for t in range(num_time): 
        work[e,t] = model.NewBoolVar("work(%i,%i)" % (e,t))
                
for e in range(num_emp):
    model.Add(sum(shift_assignment[e,s] for s in range(num_shift))==1)
    
for e in range(num_emp):
    for s in range(num_shift):
        and_ls=[]
        or_ls=[]
        for t in range(num_time):
            if shift_list[s][t]:
                and_ls.append(work[e,t])
                or_ls.append(work[e,t].Not())
            else:
                and_ls.append(work[e,t].Not())
                or_ls.append(work[e,t])
        
        or_ls.append(shift_assignment[e,s])
        model.AddBoolAnd(and_ls).OnlyEnforceIf(shift_assignment[e,s])
        model.AddBoolOr(or_ls)
        
model.Add(shift_assignment[0,2]==1)
model.Add(shift_assignment[1,1]==1)
model.Add(shift_assignment[2,3]==1)
model.Add(shift_assignment[3,4]==1)
model.Add(shift_assignment[4,0]==1)


status = solver.Solve(model) 
print("status:",status) 

res=np.zeros([num_emp,num_time])
for e in range(num_emp):
    for t in range(num_time):
        res[e,t]=solver.Value(work[e,t])
print(res)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a set of implications.

looking only at the first worker:

work = [w0, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6]

shift = [s0, s1, s2, s3, s4]

```
shift_list=[[1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
            [0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,0],
            [0,0,0,0,1,1,1]]
```

so

```
w0 <=> s0
w1 <=> or(s0, s1)
w2 <=> or(s0, s1, s2)
w3 <=> or(s1, s2, s3)
w4 <=> or(s2, s3, s4)
w5 <=> or(s3, s4)
w6 <=> s4
```

where you encode `l0 <=> or(l1, ..., ln)` by writing

```
# l0 implies or(l1, .., ln)
or(l0.Not(), l1, .., ln)  

# or(l1, .., ln) implies l0
forall i in 1..n:  
  implication(li, l0)
```